# Can't remove collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I just started learning mongoDB and I noticed a collection which is removed by .remove() command still exist after the executing.
am I doing something wrong or this is how it's supposed to work?

by using mongo

```
use testDB
db.stats() // returns "db" : "testDB","collections" : 0,"objects" : 0 
//and db.getCollectionNames() returns nothing as well
db.testCollection.insert({ test : 'abc'})
db.getCollectionNames() // [ "system.indexes", "testCollection" ]
db.testCollection.remove()
db.testCollection.find() // returns nothing
db.getCollectionNames() // [ "system.indexes", "testCollection" ]
db.stats() // "db" : "testDB","collections" : 3,"objects" : 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the point of [remove](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) operation in mongodb. It does not remove the collection, it removes all documents in the collection which specify the query. If you do `remove()` you specify nothing in your query, thus it removes everything.

To remove collection do `db.collection.drop()`

Comment: Thank you for quick and accurate answering